# Method inside another method calling using node.js restful api

Tags: node.js, rest

I am new to node.js, i am developing restful api using node.js but i don't know how to call a method inside another method.Can anyone explain how to call this.

For example see the below function

```
var myFunction = {
test1: function(){
    //code goes here
},

test2: function(){
    //how to call test1 here
    //code goes here
}};
module.exports = myFunction;
```

How can i call test1 in test2 method

Comment: Maybe explain a little more about what you're trying to achieve, so we can recommend ways how to do it correctly, instead of calling exported methods (that appear to act as middleware/controller) from within another

Comment: edited my code..please see

Answer (score 0):

You can call `test1` like this (from `test2`):

```
myFunction.test1()
```

Answer (score 0):

> index.js

```
const temp = require("./temp");
temp.test1();
temp.test2();
```

> temp.js

```
var myFunction = {
    test1: function() {
        console.log('call from temp.test1()');
    },

    test2: function() {
        console.log('call from temp.test2()');
    }
};
module.exports = myFunction;
```